# Add headline to metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, beamer-metropolis

I want to add a horizontal blue line below the frametitle of the slides using the metropolis theme. It should reach across the entire width.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title without line}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty hack: misuse the progress bar

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}

\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=blue,bg=blue}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\moloch@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title without line}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]